# Assembly Code While Loop

Tags: assembly

Hi the code asks for the users input for a limit, and it has to print the fibonancci series sequence up until that limit. For example the limit is 10, it should print 1,1,2,3,5,8. I believe my math is correct to calculate the fib,

```
while(f<=userInput) {
  f=i+j
  i=j
  j=f
  print(j)  }
```

and the value of i=0, j=1. I believe the problem is with my format2 to print out the sequence, I'm not sure. When i run the program it just prints "1" and thats it. Thanks for your help!

```
.section ".data"
prompt: .asciz "\nEnter a limit on the largest number to be displayed: "
format: .asciz "%d%c"
format2: .asciz "Fibonnaci series: %d\n"
myString: .asciz "1 "
myString2: .asciz "\n" 


.align 4
input: .word 0
nl: .asciz "\n"

define(f, l0)
define(i, l1)
define(j, l2)

.align 4
.section ".text"
.global main
main:
save %sp, -96, %sp

clr %f
clr %i             
mov 1, %j                  !initialize j=1

set   prompt, %o0           !point o0 to the prompt
call  printf                        !call printf to print the prompt
nop

set   format, %o0           !address of the format
set   input, %o1            !address of the location for the max
set   nl, %o2
call  scanf                 !reads user input, coverts to a
nop                         !number and stores at the memory referenced by input


set   format2, %o0
set   input, %o1
ld    [%o1], %o1             !userInput loaded into o1

mov  %o1, %g1               ! g1 = userInput
set  myString, %o0          ! print leading 1 in fib sequence
call printf
nop

test: 
  add  %i, %j, %f            ! f=i+j
  cmp  %f, %g1               !while( f<= userInput)
  bg   done                  ! reverse the logic of the test to branch over when f > userInput
  nop             
  mov  %j, %i                ! i=j
  mov %f, %j                 ! j=f
  mov  %j, %o1
  set  format2, %o0
  call printf                ! print J
  nop
  ba  test
  nop
done:

 set  myString2, %o0                 ! double space after fib sequence
 call printf
 nop


  ret
  restore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *The Dark* said, the calling convention allows for the called function (in this case `printf`) to change the `%o` registers. This applies to `%o0` too, meaning you should reload the `format2` in the loop. Other than that, you are missing a `nop` in the branch delay slot before the label `done`. With those changes it works for me.

Comment: That worked and got it to print, but it would print one more sequence then needed, for example i put the limit to be 90 it would print 1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144 before my terminal account$ instead of after. It should have stopped at the 89, i tried commenting out the format2 outside the loop but still not it. But my loop is Branch Greater (bg done) which means if f <= userInput then it shouldn't have. Do you have any idea for the fix of the 2? I appreciate your help

Comment: After your `bg` you still do one addition, that's why you get one more. You should move the `cmp/bg` to after the addition, before `printf` is invoked.

Comment: Great! It works finally, now I am suppose to indicate what is the greatest power of 2 that the final number printed is divisible by. Note: I am not allowed to use the divide function or any shift functions. If the number is odd, then the greatest power of 2 would be 2^0 = 1. I have an idea., convert it to binary and count the trailing zeros would give the power of 2. For example 610 in binary is 1001100010,

Comment: there is only one trailing zero so that means 2^1 = 2 or 8 in binary is 1000 and there is 3 trailing zeros so that means 2^3 = 8. so the great power of 2 that 8 is divisible by is 8. If the binary number has a trailing zero then it is odd which means it is divisible by 1. But how can we just look at the trailing zeros or one without using the shift function?

Comment: You can create a mask (starting from `1`) with which you can check each bit in a loop. To shift the mask one place to the left, add it to itself (ie. double it).

Comment: iv been looking at some examples in the book btst %mask, %sourceRegister which expands to andcc %sourceRegister, %mask, %destinationRegister, and I understand what its doing but i don't see how i can use that for my problem. How can i check each bit by bit? Maybe I can convert the dec to hex and compare bit by bit to see if that hex is equal to 0000,0001,0010,0100,1000. Thats the only 5 i need to check then i would know if it were equal then print "blah blah" since i know how many zeros that has.

Comment: `cnt=0; for(mask=1; mask && !(x&mask); mask+=mask) cnt++;`

Comment: Sorry Im still a beginner, how may i use that? can you show me an example so I can see how it works? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your loop you are testing %f against %o1, where %o1 is the user input. You are then using %o1 during your loop, so it no longer contains the user input. You need to save the user input value off somewhere first.

Comment: I just made the change and this time it still printed out just "1" and I have a error "Segmentation Fault (core dumped) I even defined g1 to see if that resolved the problem but same error.

Comment: Are you sure %o0 doesn't get changed by something (e.g. inside printf). I don't know this particular assembly, but it looks like %o0, %o1 etc are registers that may be changed by anything. You only set %o0 before the loop, so if printf changes it, then the next time you call printf (second time round the loop), %o0 may no longer point your format string, so printf will print from an invalid location (and that may cause a segmentation fault).

Comment: Im sure that it doesn't get changed, i just commented out my loop and have it just print %o1 that is right before the loop and that works, but is it because the loop is going to print more than 1 value that my format2: .asciz isn't correct? I just re-checked my math by hand it it works. I still new to assembly so it must be something technical with the printf but i can't see where the problem is.